# savesymbol shows completely wrong symbol

Tags: symbols, mnsymbol

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{bot}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\restoresymbol{MN}{bot}
\begin{document}
sda $\bot$
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image: wrong symbol]

instead of (when commenting the `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`)

[image: right symbol]

I am very confused. My goal is to use the standard `\bot` symbol while also using a few symbols from `MnSymbol`.

However: `\MNbot` rightly shows the bot symbol from `MnSymbol`.
`\origbot` however shows the same but wrong symbol as `\bot`

EDIT/*Comment on the answers*: For the uninitiated like me, the main difference between the answers of @egreg and @cfr is, that @egreg's answer uses all the standard symbols plus the `\bot` symbol from `MnSymbol`, whereas @cfr's answer uses all the symbols from `MnSymbol` plus the standard `\bot` symbol. Both work great depending on your use case.

Comment: It saves the relevant slot in the font `\char"23F`, but that's not enough to generate the correct character for several reasons. The most basic of which is that it doesn't ensure that character 23F is taken from the same font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see what `\savesymbol{bot}` and `\restoresymbol{MN}{bot}` do.

The former essentially does `\let\origbot=\bot` and then undefines `\bot`. The latter does

```
\global\let\MNbot=\bot
\global\let\bot=\origbot
```

This *might* sometimes work, but definitely not with `MnSymbol`, sorry. Why? If you try

```
\show\bot
\show\MNbot
```

after the redefinitions, you will see

```
> \bot=\mathchar"23F.

> \MNbot=\mathchar"696.
```

With `\bot` you get whatever character is in slot `"3F` of the font in math family 2, which happens not to be the expected symbol:

- `MnSymbol` doesn't use the standard encodings for symbols;
- `MnSymbol` changes ***every*** math symbol.

With your setup you get *all* math symbols from `MnSymbol`, besides `\bot` showing the wrong one (and from `MnSymbol`).

Let's see with an example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{bot}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\restoresymbol{MN}{bot}

\begin{document}

sda $\bot$

Arrow $\rightarrow$ and integral $\int$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you remove lines from 2 to 5, the output would be

[image]

So your goal is "to use the standard `\bot` symbol while also using a few symbols from MnSymbol” is definitely not achieved.

Let's say you want to use the “bottom” symbol from `MnSymbol`. Looking inside `MnSymbol.sty` we find

```
\Decl@Mn@Char\bot                    {MnSyC}{\mathord}
```

which is quite cryptic, because it doesn't tell what slot the symbol is sitting in. But we can infer it from running

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\ShowCommand{\bot}
\stop
```

that will show

```
> \bot=\mathchar"696.
```

and we're interested in the last two digits. Now we have to look for `MnSyC`:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC}         {U}  {MnSymbolC}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{MnSyC}       {bold}{U}  {MnSymbolC}{b}{n}
```

and we go back looking for `MnSymbolC`, getting

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}  {MnSymbolC}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC10
  <12->   MnSymbolC12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolC-Bold5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolC-Bold6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolC-Bold7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolC-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbolC-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC-Bold10
  <12->   MnSymbolC-Bold12}{}
```

So if you want to use the “bottom” symbol from `MnSymbol` along with the standard one, you need

```
\documentclass{report}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolC}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC10
  <12->   MnSymbolC12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolC-Bold5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolC-Bold6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolC-Bold7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolC-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbolC-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC-Bold10
  <12->   MnSymbolC-Bold12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC}{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{MnSyC}{bold}{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\MNbot}{\mathord}{MnSyC}{"96}

\begin{document}

Standard $\bot$ and MnSymbol $\MNbot$

Arrow $\rightarrow$ and integral $\int$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Yes, no less than this. Note that the other symbols in the last picture are the standard ones (like in the second picture above).

Comment: If you would specify in your last example that the arrow and the integral sign are the standard ones that would pe perfect. At the moment it sounds like they are the MnSymbol ones in the picture.

Comment: @Rubids Which is what you wanted, I guess. I added the comment.

Comment: A perfectly reasonable guess! I will probably use this solution in the future and it will certainly be useful to others.

Answer (score 5):

It saves the symbol's character slot, so *if the font encoding and family are the same*, `\bot` will produce the original symbol. But, of course, loading `MnSymbols` alters the maths font configuration so that the family is not the same. Moreover, in this case, the encoding isn't the same either. So you not only get a character from the wrong font family, you get the wrong character from the wrong font family.

However, you can set up things so you can access both symbols using your preferred commands. For example,

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\let\MNbot\bot
\DeclareSymbolFont{origsymbols}     {OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bot}{\mathord}{origsymbols}{"3F}
\begin{document}
sda $\bot  \MNbot$
\end{document}
```

Image of the output:

[image: different representations of falsehood]

[If anybody has a stacking window manager they like, preferably based on QT, which is not `kwin`, please let me know. I've about had it with KDE - and I've used KDE for over a decade.]

Comment: i think a nice addition to this answer would be how to find the 3F part.
Afaik it can be done like this:
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{fonttable}
    \begin{document}
    \xfonttable{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
    \end{document}
and see that the bot symbol is number 63 (in decimal). Convert to Hexadecimal and get 3F.

Comment: Also a mention that this uses all the Mnsymbol symbols plus the standard one for bot would be great for readers that have never had to care about font packages before.

Comment: @Rubids Huh. I just used `\show\bot` etc. Thanks for the image. Really annoyed by this update.